# USB port powers down in windows

Tags: windows-xp, usb, ipod

I am trying to charge an iPod on an XP box. I plug into the USB, it mounts as a disk. Once I dismount, so I can start using the iPod while it charges, the usb port shuts off power. what gives?

Comment: Does it charge if you leave it mounted? Have you tried it in other ports on the same computer?

Comment: Yeah, you posted that about 20secs before mine posted, so I didn't see it 'til done.  +1 for the quick solution to your own question.

Answer (score 2):

1. In Windows, click on Start > Control Panel (or Start > Settings > Control Panel).
2. Double-click on System, then open the Hardware tab.
3. Click Device Manager.
4. Click the + at Universal Serial Bus Controllers.
5. Right-click USB Root Hub and select Properties.
6. Open the Power Management tab.
7. Clear the checkmark from Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power.
8. Click OK.
9. Repeat this procedure for the USB 2.0 Hub.

Comment: If this (your own) answer solves the problem, feel free to mark it as accepted (checkmark).